# Instant messenger for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any instant messenger that works on Windows XP?

Something like Facebook Messenger, Skype, Yahoo Messenger, Gajim etc

Comment: Please for security reasons do not connect a Windows XP system to the internet. If you have an oder computer that is not capable to run a modern Windows version switch to Linux. There are distributions specialized for older systems with low resources.

Comment: Not sure about instant messaging per se, but I bet you could find an IRC client that would work on XP.  You also might be able to find an old version of something like Yahoo Messenger that would work, but I'm not sure how it would interoperate if chatting with people using newer versions.